# How input name price1, price2, price3.... in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
let arrNum = 0;

function addInput() {
  // click add input btn
  arrNum += 1;
}

<input type="text" name={ "price" + arrNum } />
<button ... onClick= { this.addInput }></button>
```

Each time users press a button, add input and arrNum += 1.

What i want when i click 3 clicks

```
<input type="text" name="price1" />
<input type="text" name="price2" />
<input type="text" name="price3" />
```

but i click

```
<input type="text" name="price3" />
<input type="text" name="price3" />
<input type="text" name="price3" />
```

Sorry, i am bad at english

Comment: your codesnippet is not working

Comment: it's a summary.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far. like the react component that matches the above scenario

Comment: ok write new answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this.

```
const addComponents = (num) => {
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        const priceName = 'price'+i;
        arr.push(<AddForm priceName= {priceName}/>); //price name will change for each loop price0, price1, price2 ...
    }

    return arr;
  }
```

And in addForm

```
 this.state = {
    price: this.props.priceName,
    largeValue: '',
    middleValue: '',
    smallValue: '',
    seValue: '',
    seseValue: '',

    largecat: la1
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add your inputs in an array in your `state`.

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = {
    inputs: ["price1"],
  };
}
```

You can then do:

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.inputs.map(
      (inputName, i) => <input type="text" name={inputName} key={i} />
    )}
    <button ... onClick= { this.addInput }></button>
  );
}

function addInput() {
  let temp = this.state.inputs.slice();
  let size = this.state.inputs.length+1;
  this.setState({inputs: temp.push("price"+length)});
}
```